# Templated move assignment operator deleted when there is a user defined move assignment operator

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, copy-constructor

I have a class with a copy constructor that is only enabled when a condition is satisfied, say for this example, when the type parameter is not a reference.  And a member that is neither movable nor copyable (say a mutex). 
 For example (https://wandbox.org/permlink/hRx51Ht1klYjN7v5)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <mutex>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;    

template <typename T>
class Something {
public:
    Something() {}

    template <typename Type = T, 
              std::enable_if_t<!std::is_reference<Type>{}>* = nullptr>
    Something(const Something&) {}

    Something& operator=(Something&&) {
        return *this;
    }

    std::mutex mutex_;
};

int main() {
    auto&& one = Something<int>{};
    auto two = one;
    std::ignore = two;
}
```

When I compile this code, I get an error saying

```
 copy constructor is implicitly deleted because 'Something<int>' has a user-declared move assignment operator
    Something& operator=(Something&&) {
               ^
1 error generated.
```

Ok, so I try to apply the same constraint to the move assignment operator

```
template <typename T>
class Something {
public:
    Something() {}

    template <typename Type = T, 
              std::enable_if_t<!std::is_reference<Type>{}>* = nullptr>
    Something(const Something&) {}

    template <typename Type = T, 
              std::enable_if_t<!std::is_reference<Type>{}>* = nullptr>
    Something& operator=(Something&&) {
        return *this;
    }

    std::mutex mutex_;
};
```

The error changes to this

```
copy constructor of 'Something<int>' is implicitly deleted because field 'mutex_' has an inaccessible copy constructor
    std::mutex mutex_;
               ^
1 error generated.
```

Any ideas on how I can go about this?  Why is the compiler complaining when I clearly want to default construct the non-movable non-copyable member?  When I remove the constraints, this compiles fine https://wandbox.org/permlink/daqWAbF40MyfDJcN

Comment: Your SFINAE is failing every time. You meant `std::is_reference_v` or `std::is_reference<Type>::value`; your current one tries to apply `operator!` to a struct which doesn't have it, and therefore encounters substitution failure whether or not it's a reference type.

Comment: @DanielH Not really, this applies implicit integer conversions, std::integral_constant is convertible to its corresponding integer type.  In this case a boolean.

Comment: Oops, yeah, I checked and still didn't see that. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The special member functions (copy/move) are identified by their signature. When you attempt to template them, you are defining templates with *another* signature, since the template parameters are part of a templates signature, and that function is unrelated to the copy/move c'tors you are attempting to disallow.

And for completeness, to quote the standard, emphasis mine:

> [**[class.copy]/2**](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/class.copy#2)
>
> **A non-template constructor** for class X is a copy constructor if its first parameter is of type X&, const X&, volatile X& or const volatile X&, and either there are no other parameters or else all other parameters have default arguments ([dcl.fct.default]).

Similar wording appears when describing the other special members. They must be non-templates.

So you aren't affecting those functions with SFINAE. And you can't affect them directly with SFINAE, since the compiler makes sure they always exist. The only way to affect their generation or lack-thereof is by inheriting (conditionally, even) from base classes, or having member data, that would cause them to be defined as deleted.

---

The silver lining, assuming nothing changes in two years, is that in C++20 it will possible to constrain a copy constructor (or any special member) with a `requires` clause:

```
Something(const Something&) requires !std::is_reference_v<T> {}
```

Comment: Interesting, I was not aware of that, so what is the solution in this case?  How do you conditionally enable/disable the special functions?

Comment: @Curious - There is no solution. Those member functions are always there in one way shape or form. Either you define them yourself, or they are **defined (as deleted)** by the compiler. You can't remove them from an overload set by yourself. Not up to C++17, and I'm not sure about C++20.

Comment: @Curious - According to my reading, and to GCC, you can do it with a C++20 compiler. Doesn't help you, but there you have it.

Comment: This is interesting, I was not aware of this restriction.  Seems like my understanding was incorrect :(

Comment: But then how does the move constructor of std::optional say this `This constructor does not participate in overload resolution unless std::is_move_constructible_v<T> is true` on cppreference?

Comment: @StoryTeller That doesn't match my reading; it looks like functions with constraints also need to themselves be templates, not just be part of templated classes.

Comment: @Curious - That is the subject for another post. But suffice it to say that move operations that are defined as deleted *by the compiler* have an exemption and may be disregarded in overload resolution (this is snice c++11, to not break legacy code). `std::optional` very likely inherits from an implementation class.

Comment: @DanielH - I read that it can appear on any function delcaration (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.decl#4). A quick lookup with the help of the draft's index didn't bring up anything to suggest otherwise.

Comment: @StoryTeller In libstdc++, they [inherit from a base class](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/optional#L987) that [conditionally enables the copy and move consructor](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/enable_special_members.h#L130), like you suggested.

Comment: @StoryTeller Huh, okay. When I looked I only saw [stuff about templates specifically](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr.constr#def:constraint), but now I see it can be both.

Comment: @DanielH - Interesting. If I read correctly, you can have separate clauses for the template arguments and the function. Peculiar.

Answer (score 2):

Suggested workaround (if I understand the requirement correctly) is to defer copy/move capability and synchronisation to base classes (which could be mixins if necessary):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <mutex>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;    

// A class for handling synchronisation
struct Synchro
{
    std::mutex mutex_;
};

// a class defining capabilities given a data type
template<class T>
struct DataManager : Synchro
{
    DataManager() {}

    DataManager(DataManager const&);
    DataManager& operator=(DataManager const&);
    DataManager(DataManager&&);
    DataManager& operator=(DataManager&&);

};

// special treatment for references
template<class Ref>
struct DataManager<Ref&> : Synchro
{
    DataManager() {}

    DataManager(DataManager const&) = delete;
    DataManager& operator=(DataManager const&) = delete;
    DataManager(DataManager&&) = delete;
    DataManager& operator=(DataManager&&) = delete;
};

// derive something from the specialised DataManager
template <typename T>
class Something : private DataManager<T>
{
public:
    Something() {}

};

int main() {
    auto&& one = Something<int>{};
    auto two = one;
    std::ignore = two;
}
```

Answers to questions in first comment:

> Thanks! If you have a template function in Something that is basically a move constructor (but with a template), then when you move an instance of Something in the case where DataManager has the move constructor deleted. Then what happens?

The reason for deferring move/copy capability to the base class is that we want to remove this concern entirely from `Something`.

> Can Something delegate construction to the default constructor of DataManager?

Yes

> What effect does inheriting from a class with a deleted constructor have?

If you don't define special constructors/destructor in the derived class (which we deliberately have not done), and we define no data objects in the derived class, it has the same effect as deferring the copy/move constructor rules to the base class. This is not the fully correct description but is effectively what happens.

> Does it implicitly delete the corresponding constructor of the derived class?

In this case, yes.

> Do the derived class constructors/assignment operators get correspondingly deleted?

Effectively in this case, yes.

Remember to define all data objects in the base class.

Comment: Thanks!  If you have a template function in `Something` that is basically a move constructor (but with a template), then when you move an instance of `Something` in the case where `DataManager` has the move constructor deleted.  Then what happens?  Can `Something` delegate construction to the default constructor of `DataManager`?  What effect does inheriting from a class with a deleted constructor have?  Does it implicitly delete the corresponding constructor of the derived class?  Do the derived class constructors/assignment operators get correspondingly deleted?

Comment: @Curious added answers to the question